# a four page spread

Tags: meaning

*This was the week that the Daily Mirror had exposed Rupert, in a four-page spread, as an adulterer.*

I am thinking about how many pages covers the text about Rupert in the Daily Mirror. If spread means 2 pages, then a four-page spread should be 8 pages. Is my calculation correct or the exact number of pages is different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in this context. A *spread* here refers to the article covering more than one column.

A one (or full) page spread means the article has covered one page (page being one side of one leaf). A two page spread means two full pages of that article (usually facing pages).

So a four page spread does literally mean four pages.